# .NET Manual Reset Event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In the code below, Main function waits for Manual Reset Event (mre) to be set.
However, before **the waiting** starts, the sync object is already set to signaled state by other thread.

So, is it safe to wait for "already signaled sync objects"?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Func), mre);
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        mre.WaitOne(100000); // Waiting for already signaled object
        Console.WriteLine("Wait Completed");
    }

    public static void Func(object state)
    {
        ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)state;
        mre.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("Mre Is Set");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting? In the above example mre.Set() is already executed before you Thread.Sleep(1500) is over, so you are getting in signaled state.

Comment: with your code, it is obvious the reset event will be set when the WaitOne code line is hit. Since Manual reset event are designed to be used the way you do here, how could it be 'unsafe' ??

Comment: I had the same question as you years ago.  Kudos to you for tinkering around with the reset events.  They're very handy for working with threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  If it's already signalled, there won't be any waiting done.  That's fine.

In fact, if you look at the return value of `WaitOne(int)` you'll see that it returns `true` if it is already set (or gets set before the timeout), and `false` if it doesn't get set within your timeout value.

That distinction is sometimes important so be aware that there is a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, the code just goes on.